# shuffling radio button in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, radio-button, shuffle, radio-group

let's say i want to make a quiz page that will shuffle the radio button option.

i've done trying to shuffle the List()  (containing radio button) in init state but it doesn't working. radio button works perfectly fine, but it won't shuffle. here's my List

```
  List<Widget> listRadioOption(){
    return [
      //this should be shuffeled 1 time after build (in init state)
      radioListTile(text: widget.option1, jawaban: ListJawaban.answer1),
      radioListTile(text: widget.option2, jawaban: ListJawaban.answer2),
      radioListTile(text: widget.option3, jawaban: ListJawaban.answer3),
      radioListTile(text: widget.option4, jawaban: ListJawaban.answer4),
      radioListTile(text: widget.option5, jawaban: ListJawaban.answer5),
    ];
  }
```

and then i use my second tot to make List but i will initialize it with listRadioOption() in initState, like this :

```
 late List<Widget> list2; //list for checking my second tot..
```

and here's my initState :

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("---- INIT STATE ----");
    listRadioOption().shuffle(); //this doesn't shuffle the option, but radio option works perfectly
    list2 = listRadioOption(); //this work if i use this as children,
    list2.shuffle(); //but it won't changing radio option value when user click in it (i dont know why)
  }
```

list2 works fine with shuffle, but ended up with user can't press any button in radio button. my listRadioOption() works fine, but can't shuffling.

and i try again using this cascade operator like this :

```
  List<Widget> listRadioOption(){
    return [
      //this should be shuffeled 1 time after build (in init state)
      radioListTile(text: widget.option1, jawaban: ListJawaban.answer1),
      radioListTile(text: widget.option2, jawaban: ListJawaban.answer2),
      radioListTile(text: widget.option3, jawaban: ListJawaban.answer3),
      radioListTile(text: widget.option4, jawaban: ListJawaban.answer4),
      radioListTile(text: widget.option5, jawaban: ListJawaban.answer5),
    ]..shuffle(); 
  }
```

it works, but it keeps shuffling when user press any radio button.
i know a little about cascade operator, but what does it mean if i used it in return statement like above code?

what i want is actually just shuffling  the radio button (1 times) and radio button will change according to user tap

can anyone help me?

here is my full code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum ListJawaban{
  answer1,
  answer2,
  answer3,
  answer4,
  answer5
}

class QuizTemplate extends StatefulWidget {
  const QuizTemplate({
    Key? key,
    required this.question,
    required this.option1,
    required this.option2,
    required this.option3,
    required this.option4,
    required this.option5,
    required this.qNumber
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String question;
  final String option1;
  final String option2;
  final String option3;
  final String option4;
  final String option5;
  final int qNumber;

  @override
  State<QuizTemplate> createState() => _QuizTemplateState();
}

class _QuizTemplateState extends State<QuizTemplate> {

  ListJawaban? _value = null;

  Widget radioListTile({required String text, required ListJawaban jawaban}){
    return RadioListTile<ListJawaban>(
      title: Text("$text"),
      value: jawaban,
      groupValue: _value,
      onChanged: (ListJawaban? newValue){
        setState(() {
          print("jawaban : $newValue");
          _value = newValue;
        });
      },
    );
  }

 
  List<Widget> listRadioOption(){
    return [
      //this should be shuffeled 1 time after build (in init state)
      radioListTile(text: widget.option1, jawaban: ListJawaban.answer1),
      radioListTile(text: widget.option2, jawaban: ListJawaban.answer2),
      radioListTile(text: widget.option3, jawaban: ListJawaban.answer3),
      radioListTile(text: widget.option4, jawaban: ListJawaban.answer4),
      radioListTile(text: widget.option5, jawaban: ListJawaban.answer5),
    ];
  }

  late List<Widget> list2; //list for checking my second tot..

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("---- INIT STATE ----");
    listRadioOption().shuffle(); //this doesn't shuffle the option, but radio option works perfectly
    list2 = listRadioOption(); //this work if i use this as children,
    list2.shuffle(); //but it won't changing radio option value when user click in it (i dont know why)
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("---- BUILD ----");
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text("${widget.qNumber}. ${widget.question}",style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
          ),),
          Builder(
            //i actually didn't need this builder, but i used it just for checking variables
            builder: (context){
              print("---- BUILDER ----");
              listRadioOption().shuffle();
              return Column(
                children: listRadioOption(),
                //children: list2,
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here my shuffle's work but i can't change values :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

enum ListJawaban{
  answer1,
  answer2,
  answer3,
  answer4,
  answer5
}

class QuizTemplate extends StatefulWidget {
  const QuizTemplate({
    Key? key,
    required this.question,
    required this.option1,
    required this.option2,
    required this.option3,
    required this.option4,
    required this.option5,
    required this.qNumber
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String question;
  final String option1;
  final String option2;
  final String option3;
  final String option4;
  final String option5;
  final int qNumber;

  @override
  State<QuizTemplate> createState() => _QuizTemplateState();
}

class _QuizTemplateState extends State<QuizTemplate> {

  ListJawaban? _value = null;

  Widget radioListTile({required String text, required ListJawaban jawaban}){
    return RadioListTile<ListJawaban>(
      title: Text("$text"),
      value: jawaban,
      groupValue: _value,
      onChanged: (ListJawaban? newValue){
        setState(() {
          print("jawaban : $newValue");
          _value = newValue;
        });
      },
    );
  }


  List<Widget> listRadioOption(){
    return [
      //this should be shuffeled 1 time after build (in init state)
      radioListTile(text: widget.option1, jawaban: ListJawaban.answer1),
      radioListTile(text: widget.option2, jawaban: ListJawaban.answer2),
      radioListTile(text: widget.option3, jawaban: ListJawaban.answer3),
      radioListTile(text: widget.option4, jawaban: ListJawaban.answer4),
      radioListTile(text: widget.option5, jawaban: ListJawaban.answer5),
    ];
  }

  late List<Widget> list2; //list for checking my second tot..

  List<Widget> option(){
    return list2;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print("---- INIT STATE ----");
    // listRadioOption().shuffle(); //this doesn't shuffle the option, but radio option works perfectly
    list2 = listRadioOption(); //this work if i use this as children,
    list2.shuffle(); //but it won't changing radio option value when user click in it (i dont know why)
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("---- BUILD ----");
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text("${widget.qNumber}. ${widget.question}",style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
          ),),
          Builder(
            //i actually didn't need this builder, but i used it just for checking variables
            builder: (context){
              print("---- BUILDER ----");
              return Column(
                children: option(),
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `listRadioOption()` is a function that returns a *new* `List` each time it is called.  You need to to save the returned `List` and shuffle *that*.

Comment: i did, it surely shuffled, but my radio button didn't change its value when user tap the radio button, like it wasn't rebuild. but i can ensure it was rebuild because i printed the newValue in setState(). i don't understand why the radio button can't change the values. @jamesdlin

Comment: If you're still having problems, then post an updated version of your code that stops calling `listRadioOption()` multiple times.

Comment: check this out @jamesdlin

Comment: Or you might be want to check my new question (with visualization my error) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71941171/radiolisttile-indicator-is-not-showing-when-i-store-it-in-listwidget-but-it-ha @jamesdlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my second answer to your question, the first question was short but here I explain what I meant in the first answer. I rewrite your code to answer your question. Just copy and paste it to the [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=e75b493dae1287757c5e1d77a0dc73f1) to play and test with it.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const Home(title: 'English Words Quiz'),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  const Home({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: QuizTemplate(
        model: QuizModel(
          question: 'They cleaned _____ shoes.',
          describe: 'Choose correct alternative',
          questionNumber: 4,
          answers: ['there', 'their', 'they´re', 'they'],
          correctAnswer: 'their',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class QuizTemplate extends StatefulWidget {
  const QuizTemplate({Key? key, required this.model}) : super(key: key);

  final QuizModel model;

  @override
  State<QuizTemplate> createState() => _QuizTemplateState();
}

class _QuizTemplateState extends State<QuizTemplate> {
  // The list outside of builder to avoid rebuilding.
  late final List<String> _answers;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _answers = widget.model.shuffled;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            child: Text(
              '${widget.model.questionNumber}',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
            ),
          ),
          title: Text(
            widget.model.question,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
          ),
          subtitle: widget.model.describe == null
              ? null
              : Text(
                  widget.model.describe!,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle2,
                ),
        ),
        for (final answer in _answers)
          RadioListTile<int>(
            title: Text(answer),
            value: widget.model.indexOf(answer),
            groupValue: widget.model.currentIndex,
            onChanged: (index) {
              setState(() {
                widget.model.updateCurrentIndex(index);
              });
            },
          ),
        if (widget.model.currentIndex != null)
          Text(
            widget.model.isCorrectAnswer
                ? 'The correct answer is ${widget.model.correctAnswer}'
                : 'The answer is incorrect',
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class QuizModel {
  QuizModel({
    required this.question,
    required this.answers,
    required this.correctAnswer,
    this.describe,
    this.questionNumber,
  })  : assert(answers.isNotEmpty, "The answers can't be empty"),
        assert(
          answers.contains(correctAnswer),
          'The answers must include correct answer, $correctAnswer is incorrect.',
        );

  final String question;
  final String? describe;
  final int? questionNumber;
  final String correctAnswer;
  final List<String> answers;

  int? _currentIndex;
  int? get currentIndex => _currentIndex;
  List<String> get shuffled => answers..shuffle();
  bool get isCorrectAnswer => indexOf(correctAnswer) == _currentIndex;

  int indexOf(String answer) => answers.indexOf(answer);

  void updateCurrentIndex(int? index) {
    _currentIndex = index;
  }
}
```

> Dart 2.17 enhanced enum will be perfect for your situation and will make your code cleaner.

Comment: ahh i see... thanks a lot sir!

Comment: updated to cleaner code for fun :)